# Oracle to_number function parameters

Tags: oracle, function

I'm having trouble with TO_NUMBER function second and third parameters. Does one of them depend on the other one? How does nls_params parameter work? I can't understand how the the result of the query

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('17.000,23', 
             '999G999D99', 
             'nls_numeric_characters='',.'' ')  
             REFORMATTED_NUMBER 
FROM   DUAL;
```

can be 17000.23. Could somebody please explain the process of the above conversion.

P.S. The above query is taken from an Oracle Database SQL Expert Certificate preparation book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I'll answer my own question. While using `TO_NUMBER` function I missed the important point that, whatever I get from `TO_NUMBER` function is going to be a number. And a number does not include anything else than decimal point and E scientific notation. So 17,788.99 is not actually a number but is rather the string representation of 17788.99.

If we try to subtract 500 from 17,788.99 we'll fail.(Well, Oracle implicitly converts numeric strings to numbers and vice-versa, but principally we can't perform arithmetic operations between strings and numbers). I'm sure that `TO_NUMBER` function is almost never used to select a column value. It's rather used to be able to make arithmetic operations. Instead, we use `TO_CHAR` to show a column value or any numeric expression in a neat, easy to read format. The fomat models and nls_params are not only for `TO_NUMBER` function, but for `TO_CHAR` as well.

Comment: I guess if you were loading external data into a table you may find the to_number formatting really handy.

Comment: Yeah,I forgot about that. Off course, we can't insert string value into a number field.

Answer (score 6):

you are telling the `TO_NUMBER` function that, 
the two characters `,.` in nls_numeric_characters represent the decimal and thousand seperator

```
G (thousands seperator) = .
D (decimal seperator)   = ,
```

so it sees the number as seventeen thousand point twenty three.

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/olap.101/b10339/x_stddev022.htm#i78653